# Can I use asterisk as wildcard within a postcode/zipcode in the Table Rates for Shipping Calculations?

Tags: shipping, table-rates

Can I use asterisk within a postcode/zipcode in the Table Rates for Shipping Calculations in Magento?

For example:

```
GY1*
```

Would match all the postcodes that began with GY1.

If this cant be done, is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

No. The table rates only use a single '*' for 'any', but do not allow expressions with wild cards.

#### Source: `Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate`

```
    // Render destination condition
    $orWhere = '(' . implode(') OR (', array(
        "dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = :region_id AND dest_zip = :postcode",
        "dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = :region_id AND dest_zip = ''",

        // Handle asterix in dest_zip field
        "dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = :region_id AND dest_zip = '*'",
        "dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = '*'",
        "dest_country_id = '0' AND dest_region_id = :region_id AND dest_zip = '*'",
        "dest_country_id = '0' AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = '*'",

        "dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = ''",
        "dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = :postcode",
        "dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = '*'",
    )) . ')';
    $select->where($orWhere);
```

You will need to rewrite this code or use a shipping extension that allows postcode ranges. I can recommend [WebShopApps](http://webshopapps.com/).